# Bulk Insert Code Before </body> Tag in 100 Files

Tags: php, html, sed, awk, bulkinsert

I'd like to insert

```
<?php include_once('google_analytics.php'); ?>
```

before the closing body tag of about 100 php files.  Unfortunately the person who made the site didn't make a header or footer template.

What is the best way to do this?  I've tried using grep/find for getting a list of files and piping the results through xargs to sed, but I've had no luck.  I probably have the regex wrong.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Also, are there any graphical tools for Apple OS X that you would recommend?

Thanks,
Mike

**edit**

```
find . -print0 -name "*.php" | xargs -0 perl -i.bak -pe 's/<\/body>/<?php include_once("google_analytics.php"); ?>\n<\/body>/g'
```

works.

Comment: Since you are doing this: once you come up with a solution, you might want to instead include_once("footer.php") and "header.php" so that you can make these kinds of changes more easily in the future!

Comment: rascher: Excellent suggestion.

Comment: you mac guys... why would you need a graphical tool for a text replacement problem?

Comment: I don't know, rascher.  I think it might be misleading to do that and not put all the rest of the common footer code in footer.php. It doesn't really end there either, I should probably make a header.php as well.

Nickf, good point.  What is wrong with this?
grep -lz "</body>" * | xargs -0 perl -i.bak -pe 's/\<\/body\>/<?php include("google_analytics.php"); ?>\n<\/body>/g'

Comment: mswebersd: What is the effect of that grep statement?

Comment: Actually, is the backslash after the first body in the r.e. necessary?

Comment: Grab any documents in the folder that have a body tag (some don't), and list the filenames with a null character afterward to make the list compatible with xargs... I think.  I was hoping that it would do the same thing as find's print0.

Comment: I think so because I'd like to match on the closing body tag.  You're referring to the backslash before the word body, correct?  Or are you referring to the backslash before the less than sign?

Comment: mswebersd: Do you see which backslash I'm asking about?  ... -pe 's/\<\/body\> ... the last one in this fragment

Comment: It looks like you're escaping that greater-than sign, no?

Comment: OH *after* sorry I read before for some reason.  Yeah, probably not necessary.

Comment: Yes you are correct- the greater than sign.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask before is what do you actually see happening when you do this command?  What is the effect of that statement?  Might point you toward where things are going wrong.

Comment: find . -print0 -name "*.php" | xargs -0 perl -i.bak -pe 's/<\/body>/<?php include_once("google_analytics.php"); ?>\n<\/body>/g' works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed:

```
 sed -i s/'<\/body>'/"<?php include_once('google_analytics.php'); ?>\n<\/body>"/ *.htm
```

The `-i` option edits the file in place. If you say `-iBAK` then it will create a backup of the file before editing it.

Comment: Alright so all that perl nonsense was unnecessary.  Good to know. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in GUI tools, download TextMate. Put all 100 files in a folder and open that folder with TM. This will put TM in project mode, and you'll see all the files in a sidebar. Now, do `Edit>Find>Find In Project`, put `</body>` in the "find" field, `<?php include_once('google_analytics.php'); ?></body>` in the "replace" field, hit replace and let it run.

Answer (score 2):

#### this calls for an *ed script*

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.html; do
ed $i << \eof
?</body>?s/^/<?php include_once('google_analytics.php'); ?>&/
w
q
eof
done
```

It fires up one of the first (literally) programs ever written for Unix, [Ken Thompson's `ed(1)` text editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) on each file and makes the necessary edit. If you want it to work on specific files rather than on every `.html` in the directory, just change `*.html` to `"$@"`.

Reading the Wikipedia link just now, I learned something interesting.  Ken Thompson made the first actual application of regular expressions, apparently they were just a mathematical expression until he wrote ed(1).

Comment: Sweet, going out now, but I'll give it a go when I get back.  Thank you.

Comment: haha, re: your edit: check out my *brilliant* description of the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085404/what-is-regular-expression/1085469#1085469

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply an array with filenames in `$files` to make the following solution work:

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $txt = file_get_contents($file);

    $txt = str_replace('</body>', '<?php include_once(\'google_analytics.php\'); ?>'."\n".'</body>', $txt);

    file_put_contents($file, $txt);
}
```

Comment: Another smart way to do it.  Thanks.  I could just stick in a directory_iterator and be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver will do a find/replace for the entire local site; I'm sure other html editors would as well.

Comment: Thanks... Dreamweaver is too expensive for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDE's like dreamweaver provide functionality to do find and replace in many files, entire folders etc. You can use one of those and do a find and replace replacing the close body tag with the code you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer, but is PHP a valid XML format?  It doesn't look like it but what do I know.  Even if it is the success of this answer may depend more on whether the files you are working with are valid PHP.  But...if it is it would be fairly simple to use an XML transform (xslt) to match the body tag, copy its content and append a new tag after the matched content.

Comment: I'm not sure how XML parsers would handle <?php tags. BUT I'm 100% positive that the HTML itself wouldn't make it through an XML parser.

Good suggestion though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Worth a shot though.

Answer (score -1):

What about a replace on

```
</body>
```

with

```
<?php include_once('google_analytics.php'); ?></body>
```

?

Comment: Maybe what he wants to do and what he actually did are two different things?