# Can you use regular expressions to implement the shunting algorithm?

Tags: regex, algorithm

Can you implement the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) in terms of regular expressions?

Comment: Out of curiosity is this something you'd actually want to do or is it more of an academic curiosity?

Comment: It's a tribute question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161553/can-the-shunting-yard-algorithm-parse-posix-regular-expressions/4161681#4161681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has been answered here: [Can the shunting yard algorithm parse POSIX regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161553/can-the-shunting-yard-algorithm-parse-posix-regular-expressions/4161681#4161681)

> I will say that the answer to your question is "no, you cannot
> implement the shunting yard algorithm using a regular expression."
> This is for the same reason you cannot parse arbitrary HTML using
> regular expressions. Which boils down to this:
>
> Regular expressions do not have a stack. Because the shunting yard
> algorithm relies on a stack (to push and pop operands as you convert
> from infix to RPN), then regular expressions do not have the
> computational "power" to perform this task.
>
> This glosses over many details, but a "regular expression" is one way
> to define a regular language. When you "use" a regular expression, you
> are asking the computer to say: "Look at a body of text and tell me
> whether or not any of those strings are in my language. The language
> that I defined using a regular expression." I'll point to [this most
> excellent answer which you and everyone reading this should upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085404/what-is-regular-expression/1085469#1085469)
> for more on regular languages.
>
> So now you need some mathematical concept to augment "regular
> languages" in order to create more powerful languages. If you were to
> characterize the shunting yard algorithm as an realization of a model
> of computational power, then you might say that the algorithm would be
> described as a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_free_grammar) (hey what do you know, that
> link uses an expression parse tree as an example.) A [push-down
> automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton). Something with a stack.
>
> If you are less-than-familiar with automata theory and complexity
> classes, then those wikipedia articles are probably not that helpful
> without explaining them from the ground up.
>
> The point being, you may be able to use regex to help writing shunting
> yard. But regex are not very good at doing operations that have an
> arbitrary depth, which this problem has. So I would not spend too much
> time going down the regex avenue for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so. Regular expressions can only match regular languages (See [Regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)), while infix expressions are a kind of context-free language (See [Context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language)). For example, you cannot match expressions made of properly matched parentheses with a regular expression.