# Need to replace a character in a string with two new values

Tags: javascript, string

```js
var Str = "_Hello_";
var newStr = Str.replaceAll("_", "<em>");
console.log(newStr);
```

it out puts `<em>Hello<em>` 
I would like it to output `<em>Hello</em>`
but I have no idea how to get the `</em>` on the outer "_", if anyone could help I would really appreciate it. New to coding and finding this particularly difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Replace two underscores in one go, using a regular expression for the first argument passed to `replaceAll`:

```js
var Str = "_Hello_";
var newStr = Str.replaceAll(/_([^_]+)_/g, "<em>$1</em>");
console.log(newStr);
```

NB: it is more common practice to reserve PascalCase for class/constructor names, and use camelCase for other variables. So better `str =`, ...etc.

Comment: Certainly this is a dupe...

Comment: now OP has a new question: what is a regular expression :D

Comment: Just in case: [what is a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085404/what-is-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as a regex replacement using a capture group:

```js
var str = "_Hello_ World!";
var newStr = str.replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "<em>$1</em>");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that code works, just to better my understanding, would you be able to explain the (.*?) and  $1, as I have not seen this before

Comment: The `$1` in the replacement is called a _capture group_, and it refers to the `(.*?)` term in the regex pattern, which is whatever sits in between the underscores.

Comment: Thank you, so if I wanted to apply it to a larger string, with words that both have and don’t have underscores, what would I have to change?

Comment: This answer should work just the same already.